# Docker Engine Hyper-V Proxy - Windows 10 Not working

Tags: windows, docker, networking, proxy, vpn

When working behind a corporate proxy (automatically activated in Windows) by Cisco AnyConnect(v4.7.03052) VPN, I'm unable to pull any docker image either from our docker nexus registry or the official registry.
Funny enough, if I set the proxy settings in the config.json and pass the proxy as build-arg my containers are able to build(from previously pulled images) and talk to the exterior.
**Only the docker engine is unable to access the internet through the proxy.**

I've already tried the following:

- Set the HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY as environments variables
- Set the proxy settings in the Docker Desktop proxy section - [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/)
- Set the resources network IP to the non-secured Cisco AnyConnect routes IPv4
- No firewall rules seems to block the outbound request from the docker engine service.
- Edit the deamon.json used by the docker service to register the mirror registries.

Stackoverflow answers not working in this case: [docker-win10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272933/docker-at-windows-10-proxy-propagation-to-containers-not-working);  [docker on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669115/docker-on-windows-with-a-proxy);  [docker image proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777036/build-docker-image-on-windows-proxy-issue)

**Platform info:**

- Win 10 - Build 19401
- Docker Desktop 4.4.4(73704)
- Docker Engine 20.12.12  (Linux container on Hyper-V)
- Cisco AnyConnect v4.7.03052

**Error message on docker pull**:

```
λ  docker pull traefik:2.0
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Based on the similar [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958380/docker-desktop-3-2-2-on-window-10-home-crashes-with-error-error-during-connect) briefly executing the command below had it working for a short time:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a regression that slipped in the 4.4.4 see [github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12503).
It seems to have been resolved in the [v4.5.0](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12503#issuecomment-1032170661)